# How to set focus on textbox on linkbutton click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this java script function

```
function showHideSearchPanel(dv) {

var Header = dv == 'Charts' ? 'ChartSearch' : 'ReportSearch';
var div = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dv" + Header;
var panel = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnl" + Header;
var hiddenField = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdn" + Header + "Mode";

// I try to add this code in js but it not work
**var serchtextbox = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearchName");
if (serchtextbox != null) {
    serchtextbox.focus();
}**
// I try to add this code in js but it not work

if ($("#" + div).attr('display') != 'block') {
    window.status = 'Expanding contents....';
    $("#" + div).slideToggle("slow");
    $("#" + div).attr('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#" + div).attr('display', 'block');
    window.status = 'Done';
}
else {
    window.status = 'Collapsing contents....';
    $("#" + div).hide("slow");
    $("#" + div).attr('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#" + div).attr('display', 'none');
    window.status = 'Done';
}
$("#" + hiddenField).attr('value', ($("#" + hiddenField).attr('value') == 'On' ? 'Off' : 'On'));
```

}

This is my simple menu
[image: My Search Menu]

When click on search button i want set focu on search textbox which is in below image
[image: Click on search table show]

Comment: May i see your aspx markup too

Comment: In aspx page jsut call this `lnkSearchReports.SetAttribute("onclick", Reports.Rows.Count > 0 ? "javascript:showHideSearchPanel('Reports'); return false;" : "javascript:return false;");` @ Akhil Sekharan

Comment: refer this code when i am googling and when i `debugging the js` `searchtextbox` in null so that's put that

Comment: Then check the id (ClientID) of the text field

Comment: Try setting the ClientID to static for the text box, for now

Comment: var serchtextbox = document.getElementById("txtSearchName");

Comment: `var serchtextbox = document.getElementById('<%= ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearchName.ClientID %>');` but not set focus @ Andreas

Comment: `var serchtextbox = document.getElementById("txtSearchName");` not set @ Akhil Sekharan

Comment: any one give idea about that...!!